# Customizing UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a custom button I want to add onto the navigation bar. So here's what I have so far in my `RootViewController` (which inherits `UIViewController`, the `UINavigationController` is added through the `AppDelegate`):

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *share = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(share:)];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = share;
```

Here's how my `UINavigationController` is set up:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Why is this not working?

**EDIT:**

It worked after I replaced `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` with `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`. Why is that? My rootviewcontroller is of type `UIViewController` and I should access `navigationItems` through `navigationController`. What is `navigationController` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It worked after I replaced self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. Why is that?

Every instance of a UIViewController has a navigationItem. This includes UINavigationController, which is a subclass of UIViewController.

navigationItem is used by a UINavigationController to update its visual state when a new view controller appears. When you modify `self.navigationController.navigationItem`, you are modifying what would be displayed if you had nested UINavigationControllers. In practice, you will never modify the navigationItem of a UINavigationController because you will not have nested navigation controllers.

As you've discovered, you must modify the view controller's `navigationItem` in order for the changes to take affect in the navigation controller.

> What is navigationController in this case?

`navigationController` is a reference to the UINavigationController that the view controller represented by `self` is currently contained within.

For example:

```
UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

// This is TRUE: viewController.navigationController == navController
```

Comment: Alright so each `UIViewController` contains a reference to its navigation controller using the proeprty `navigationController`. But `navigationItem` is a property of `UIViewController`, and not `UINavigationController` (`UINavigationController inherits it, since its a subclass of `UIViewController). I guess it might be a common misconception that `navigationItem` is a property of `UINavigationController`. One more Q, so what if the ViewController has no navbar, doesn't it make more sense to have it a property of `UINavigationController` instead?

Comment: View controllers don't own the navbar, the navigation controller does. Imagine if only the navigation controller had a navigation item. This would mean that every time one of your view controllers appears it would have to explicitly reset the navigation item properties.

Comment: So the view controller has some sort of `weak` pointer to the navbar? If the view controller does not own it, then how come `navigationItem` is a property of the view controller? What is the relationship between the view controller and `navigationItem`? A weak pointer?

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Apple UINavigationController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) by Updating the Navigation Bar, it is stated that

- If the new top-level view controller has a custom left bar button
  item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom left bar button
  item, set the ***leftBarButtonItem*** property of the view controller’s
  navigation item.
- If the new top-level view controller has a custom right bar button
  item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom right bar button
  item, set the ***rightBarButtonItem*** property of the view controller’s
  navigation item.